How can I configure Nginx as a reverse proxy on Windows Server 2022 to route traffic through an external IP
I am working on a project where I need to set up Nginx as a reverse proxy on Windows Server 2022. My goal is to configure Nginx so that when users access a specific port (25400) on my server, they see the content from https://example.com, but with traffic routed through an external IP address instead of my server’s IP address.
What I have tried:
I have attempted to configure Nginx with the following settings:
Listening on port 25400
Proxying requests to https://example.com
SSL configurations and various headers
However, I am unsure how to ensure that the traffic to https://example.com is routed through the external IP address and not directly through my server’s IP.
How can I configure Nginx to achieve this setup where the content from https://example.com is routed through an external IP address?
Additional Details:
Nginx version: [your version here]
External IP address: [provide the IP or note if not yet configured]
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
nginx.conf :
        worker_processes 1;
        pid logs/nginx.pid;

        events {
            worker_connections 1024;
        }

        http {
            include       mime.types;
            default_type  application/octet-stream;

            server {
            listen 25400;

            location / {
                proxy_pass https://www.example.com;

                proxy_buffers 8 16k;
                proxy_buffer_size 32k;

                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_ssl_verify on;
                proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
                
                proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate ca-certificates.crt;

                proxy_ssl_certificate cert.pem;
                proxy_ssl_certificate_key cert.key;

                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                proxy_hide_header Location;
                proxy_hide_header Refresh;
                proxy_hide_header Strict-Transport-Security;
                proxy_cookie_domain www.example.com localhost;
                proxy_cookie_path / /;
                proxy_cookie_flags ~ Secure HttpOnly SameSite=None;
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
                add_header Pragma "no-cache";
                add_header Expires "0";
                sub_filter '<meta http-equiv="refresh"' '<!-- removed meta refresh -->';
                sub_filter 'https://www.example.com' 'http://localhost:25400';
                sub_filter_once off;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;
                    return 204;
                }
                proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
                proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                proxy_send_timeout 300s;
                gzip on;
                gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/xml text/xml text/javascript;
                gzip_vary on;
                proxy_buffering off;
            }

            location @no_redirects {
                return 200 "Redirect Blocked!";
            }

            location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
                expires off;
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
                proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
                proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
            }
            
            location ~* \.svg$ {
                proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
                proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
            }
          }
        }

